# conversion error while converting string into integer after redirecting on same page

Tags: jsp

I'm doing my first jsp programming but i'm getting following error while converting the string conversion into integer on the  same page but if i redirect parameters to another page they work properly
following is errori'm getting
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /age.jsp at line 18
`n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age1"));
ans= n1 +5 ;`

JSP code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Age Finder</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <form action="age.jsp">
         Age:>
         <input type="text" name="age1" autofocus> <br>
         <input type="submit" name="btn">
       </form>
       <%!
        int n1,ans;
       %>
       <%
        n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age1"));
        ans=n1+5;
       %>
      <b>Your age after 5 years will be <%= ans %> years</b>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Please share the relevant jsp code where you do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request doesn't have a parameter named `age1`. It will return `null`. that's why you are getting this error. In your JSP Form, you have input text named `age1`,that's it. This parameter `age1` will be set in the request when this form is submitted to the server for processing. If you want to get the value of `age1` field after it is typed, you can use `javascript` event like `onblur()` on input text field `age1`.

Comment: Yes, if you pass `null` to `Integer.parseInt()`. it will throw error

Comment: you can add null check before conversion like this `if(request.getParameter("age1")!=null)n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age1"));`